# Bootstrap CSS - Column 3 under Column 2 on resizing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is the sample HTML page I have. On resizing, I have a requirement to display Column3 under Column2 first and on reducing screen width further, display Column3 under Column2 under Column1.

```
Column1    Column2    Column3
```

On resizing stage 1 (tablet width)

```
Column1   Column2
          Column3
```

On resizing further (mobile width)

```
Column1
Column2
Column3
```

My current code:

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
    <p>Resize this responsive page to see the effect!</p>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h3>Column 1</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
        <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h3>Column 2</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
        <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h3>Column 3</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
        <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve such a thing **you should use `offset`**. The **`offset` attribute will push or pull elements** with your desired settings.

### How to deal with it?

In order to get what you wanted you should divide your breakpoints into 3 major ones (So I just went with `md`, `sm`, `xs` which are the major ones in [bootstrap 3.4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#overview)). Then I told the bootstrap I want 3 columns in a row by determining `col-md-4` for each column. Then I told them I want each of them to fill a whole row when the window width is small with `col-xs-12`. The tricky one was telling bootstrap that I want 2 columns in each row in small devices (not extra-small `xs`), so I went with `col-sm-6`. Then I have to specify I want to push my third column for one whole column then I went with `col-sm-offset-6` and then to make sure the `offset` won't take long for next breakpoint I just declared this one-two `col-md-offset-0` to make sure offset in medium devices (`md`) is none.

So your final code should be something like this:

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
    <p>Resize this responsive page to see the effect!</p>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <h3>Column 1</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
        <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <h3>Column 2</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
        <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-0 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-6 col-xs-12">
        <h3>Column 3</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
        <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**NOTE:** You can read more about `offset` [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#grid-responsive-resets).

Comment: I didn't know how to ask a follow up question with formatting. I created another question instead. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61724553/fix-first-div-and-only-resize-the-second-div-column-3-under-column-2?noredirect=1&lq=1