# Fix first Div and only resize the second Div - column 3 under column 2

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is actually a follow up question to 
[Bootstrap CSS - Column 3 under Column 2 on resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61723300/bootstrap-css-column-3-under-column-2-on-resizing)

I would actually like to fix the first div and not move it at all

Small devices:

```
A      column1
grade  column2
       column3
```

Medium device:

```
A      column1  column2
grade           column3
```

Large devices:

```
A      column1  column2  column3
grade
```

and only move the other columns on resizing as per the solution to my original question.

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
    <p>Resize this responsive page to see the effect!</p>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-1">
        <div class="row">
          <h1>A</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <span>grade</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-11">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <h3>Column 1</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
            <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <h3>Column 2</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
            <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-0 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-6 col-xs-12">
            <h3>Column 3</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
            <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by fixing the `div`?

Comment: @SMAKSS, I have edited the question with two pictures. First on resizing to tablet view, then resizing to mobile view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `flex` for responsiveness it will take care of things for you:

here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/50zrkuqa/)

[image]

and

[image]

```css
.container>.row{
  display:flex;

}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
    <p>Resize this responsive page to see the effect!</p>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-1 both">
        <div class="row">
          <h1>A</h1>
        </div>
        
        
        
        <div class="row">
          <span>grade</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-md-11">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <h3>Column 1</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
            <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <h3>Column 2</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
            <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-0 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-6 col-xs-12">
            <h3>Column 3</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
            <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```